Contabilizar cuantas palabras hay en un texto Alfabéticamente java
Dado un archivo llamado names.txt ordenado alfabéticamente imprime cuantas palabras hay dependiendo de su primera letra, si alguien sabe una mejor respuesta ya q esta omite la ultima letra y no es muy limpio el código, como lo haría usted y como lo documentaria
import java.io.*;
public class Archivo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "src/text/names.txt";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String name;
            int letra =65;
            int count=1;
            while (reader.ready()){
                name= reader.readLine();
                int car =name.charAt(0);
                if (letra==car) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println((char) (car-1)+" = "+count);
                    count=1;
                    letra++;
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

He rehecho el código con un array para guardar la cuenta de cada palabra dependiendo de su primera letra, lo bueno es que funciona aunque estén desorganizadas las palabras, pero un contra es que como es un array crea espacio para cada letra indiferentemente si existe o no.
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "src/text/names.txt";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            int[] count=new int[26];
            int letter =65;
            while (reader.ready()){
                char nameChar= reader.readLine().charAt(0);
                int index=(int)(nameChar)-65;
                if (nameChar!=letter){
                    letter =nameChar;

                }
                count[index]=count[index]+1;
            }
            for (int i=0;i<26;i++){
                if (count[i]!=0){
                    System.out.println(((char) (i+65))+" = "+count[i]);
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
} 

names.txt
Andrew, Anna, Benjamín, Charles, Christian, David


Hola Arturo, bienvenido, sería de gran ayuda que pusieras un ejemplo del "txt", y que aclarases si hay que contar la cantidad total de palabras, la cantidad de primeras letras distintas o que?;

Hola, Marce, un placer saludarte. Gracias por la bienvenida.
Un ejemplo del texto y del resultado querido seria:
Texto {Andrew, Anna, Benjamín, Charles, Christian, David}
El código tendría que analizar que hay 2 palabras que empiezan con "A", una empieza con "B", otras dos con "C" y una con "D".

Te recomiendo separar en métodos la parte en la que cuentas, eso evitará que tengas que depurar todo el programa, yo lo hice así: https://javapro.org/programming-languages/java-string-count-elements-with-dukescript/

Vamos por dos caminos, ya que lo que pones como "txt" no estaría de acuerdo con lo que codificas.
Si el ejemplo de "txt" es correcto:
String path = "src/text/names2.txt";
  try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( path ) );
     int[] count = new int[ 26 ];
     int letter = 65;
       // como tenemos una sola linea, debemos generar un array a partir de ella,
       // eliminandole antes los espacios en blanco
     String palabras[] = reader.readLine().replace( " ", "" ).split( "," );
       // iteramos sobre el array y el resto del código se mantiene igual
     for( String palabra : palabras ) {
        char nameChar = palabra.charAt( 0 );
          // solo por innecesarios, eliminamos algunoa paréntesis
        int index = ( int ) nameChar - 65;
        if( nameChar != letter ) {
           letter = nameChar;
        }
        count[ index ] = count[ index ] + 1;
     }
     for( int i = 0; i < 26; i ++ ) {
        if( count[ i ] != 0 ) {
             // solo por innecesarios, eliminamos algunoa paréntesis
           System.out.println( ( char ) ( i + 65 ) + " = " + count[ i ] );
        }
     }
     reader.close();
  }
  catch( IOException e ) {
     System.out.println( e );
  }
}

Si en cambio, el "txt" tiene el siguiente formato:
Andrew
Anna
Benjamín
Charles
Christian
David
String path = "src/text/names.txt";
  try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( path ) );
     int[] count = new int[ 26 ];
     int letter = 65;         
     while( reader.ready() ) {
          // solo es necesaria esta corrección, que consiste en eliminar los espacios en blanco
        char nameChar = reader.readLine().replace( " ", "" ).charAt( 0 );
        int index = ( int ) nameChar - 65;
        if( nameChar != letter ) {
           letter = nameChar;
        }
        count[ index ] = count[ index ] + 1;
     }
     for( int i = 0; i < 26; i ++ ) {
        if( count[ i ] != 0 ) {
           System.out.println( ( char ) ( i + 65 ) + " = " + count[ i ] );
        }
     }
     reader.close();
  }

